# How to enter text in textfield from 5 pixels after in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, text-alignment

I have `UITextField` of which I've added an image.

Everything looks good, except that the text starts from zero X-coordinate, but I want it to start after 5 pixels in text field.

Answer (score 0):

put a left view into your text filed as such :

```
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, textField.frame.size.height)];
    textField.leftView = paddingView;
    [paddingView release];
    textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do this.

- Add an image of your textfeld
- Add an uitextfield with custom type
- set frame of the added uitextfield & move 5 pixels at right than the image

Checkout attached image for a detailed knowledge

[image: In attached picture you can see gray is an image for the textfield, & inside it I've added textfield 5 px right from gray image with type roundrect, just for the understanding purpose, you have to ake custom type]

Enjoy Programming !

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest Answer :**

**1)** Take one `UIImageView`. Add that Image for `UITextField` in `UIImageView`.

**2)** Add `UITextField` with **"No Border"** above that `UIImageView` (5 Pixels Right on that `UIImageView`).

GoodLuck !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one

```
  UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    // add 5 (width) pixel for your space
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0 ,5, txtFld.frame.size.height);

    txtFld.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    txtFld.leftView = imageView;
```

And see in this image for more info.

[image]